# About the statement of Lemma 2-10 on p.35 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak. Is $A$ open or closed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, inverse-function-theorem

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

The following lemma is on p.35 in this book.

> **Lemma 2-10** : Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. If there is a number $M$ such that
> $| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$, then
> $$
> |f(x)-f(y)| \leq n^2 M |x-y|
> $$
> for all $x,y \in A$.

---

If $A$ is an open rectangle, then "$| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$" is strange because the interior of $A$ is equal to $A$.
So, if $A$ is an open rectangle, "$| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in $A$" is natural.
So, I think $A$ is a closed rectangle.

---

But if $A$ is a closed rectangle, then the author didn't need to write the following since this automatically holds:

> If there is a number $M$ such that
> $| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$

---

Is $A$ open or closed?
Since this lemma is used in the proof of the inverse function theorem, so I think it is best to read the proof of the inverse function theorem first.
I think I can decide $A$ is open or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lemma, in general, only assumes the inequality and not the openness or closedness of the rectangle, just that it is *some* rectangle. As you've pointed out, if $A$ is a closed rectangle, then the inequality he assumes is automatically satisfied. When the rectangle is open, the assumption is not redundant (e.g. $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $A = (0,1)$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will read the proof of the inverse function theorem because this lemma is used in the proof. Maybe I can decide if $A$ is closed or open.

Comment: The lemma is true if the rectangle is open and also if it is closed.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Spivak is using a closed rectangle $U$ in the proof of the Inverse Function Theorem and this $U$ is contained in some larger open set on which $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @DavidPerrella Thank you very much for your information.

Comment: @DavidPerrella Now I understand your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I read the proof of the inverse function theorem.

I wonder why the author didn't write as follows:

> **Lemma 2-10'** : Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed rectangle and let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. Let $M$ be a number such that
> $| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in $A$, then
> $$
> |f(x)-f(y)| \leq n^2 M |x-y|
> $$
> for all $x,y \in A$.

This lemma (Lemma 2-10') is sufficient for the proof of the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelevant whether $A$ is open, closed or neither. Spivak could prove the slightly more general

> **Lemma**: Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and differentiable in the interior of $A$. If there is a number $M$ such that
> $| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$, then
> $$
> |f(x)-f(y)| \leq n^2 M |x-y|
> $$
> for all $x,y \in A$.

Note that Spivak actually only considers functions $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ because "considering only functions
defined on $\mathbb R^n$ streamlines the statement of theorems and
produces no real loss of generality. He defines such $f$ to be differentiable on $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ if $f$ is differentiable at all $a \in A$. A function $f : A \to \mathbb R^m$ is called differentiable if it has an extension $\tilde f : \mathbb R^n  \to \mathbb R^m$ which is differentiable on some open $U \supset A$. Note that if $A$ is **open**, then we may take **any** extension  of $f$, for example $\tilde f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin A$. This works because differentiability at $a \in A$ only depends only the values of $f$ close to $a$, thus on the values of $f$ contained in the open set $A$.

The proof of the above Lemma uses the mean value theorem for functions $\phi : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$. It says thatif $\phi$ is continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$,  then $\phi(b) - \phi(a) = (b-a)\phi'(z)$ with some $z \in (a,b)$. Now osberve that if $f$ is differentiable  in the interior of $A$, then all $D_jf^i$ exist in the interior of $A$.